# Scrolling code blocks glitch

Tags: bug, code-formatting

This is me trying to scroll left and right on this code block (animated):

[image]

Here are the still images:

[image]

[image]

This is a copy of the problematic code block, which I first found in [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/553671)

```
dpkg was interrupted, you must manually run 'sudo dpkg --configure -a' to correct the problem
```

The problem appears to be the precise length of the code block (93 chars).

When I resize it to 92 or 94 chars, it is fine:

[image]

[image]

[Screencast on YouTube](http://youtu.be/gOFdb4_BWb0)

My System:

- Ubuntu 14.04.1 with Chrome 39.0.2171.65 (latest)
- Zoom levels of 75%, 90%, 100%, 110% (above that it creates a working scrollbar, below it removed the scrollbar entirely)
- Screen: 1024x1280, 17.1", 43.37cm

Comment: On Windows here, tested it with Firefox(34), and chrome(39) - nothing out of the ordinary happened. This might be a browser and OS specific bug?

Comment: Possibly... Idk, but it's still doing it! Not in Firefox though...